# Non-www to www in Laravel php script Not Redirect Problem

Tags: php, laravel, no-www

My website does not redirect from exsample.com to www .exsample.com.

My website is built in laravel

My htaccess file is as below.

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 406 /


# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes

# Block files
<Files ~ "\.(env|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Even if page rules are created by Cloudflare, it does not work